# how to forward specific port from wlan0 to eth0

Tags: wifi, camera, port-forwarding

I have a RaspberryPi 2 with an IP camera ([SND-7084](https://www.samsung-security.com/products/security-cameras/network-cameras/fixed-domes/SND-7084.aspx)) connected to it with static IP 192.168.1.2
When browsing in the RPi to 192.168.1.2:4567 I can see the video streaming from the camera.

I want to be able to add a WiFi dongle to the RPi and connect to the streaming video from any computer in my home network by clicking the RPi wlan0 IP. for example: browsing to 10.0.0.5:5555 (the RPi wlan0 IP and a new port) will be routed to the eth0 IP 192.168.1.2:4567.

can this be done?

I found this [LINK](http://www.glennklockwood.com/sysadmin-howtos/rpi-wifi-island.html) which forward all wlan0 ports to eth0 but I want to be able to use the RPi for other services in different ports (80,443,22,etc.)

Thanks

Comment: Please  `netstat -nap | grep -w 4567`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're running trusty ol' iptables on your Pi (i.e. you haven't replaced it with something else), run this command (either as root or with `sudo`) on your Pi:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5555 -i wlan0 \
         -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:4567
```

You might have to do `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` before this will work, but I *think* that's only necessary for "regular" NAT (i.e. if you were running your Pi as your network's edge router/gateway).

This command does the following:

1. `-t nat -A PREROUTING` Without too much detail, this is where we put rules like this one
2. `-p tcp` Selects the TCP protocol
3. `--dport 5555` Matches incoming traffic to the Pi's port 5555
4. `-i wlan0` Matches traffic coming in on the Pi's wlan0 interface
5. `-j DNAT` Tells iptables we're doing "Destination Network Address Translation", aka "port forwarding"
6. `--to 192.168.1.2:4567` This is the host we're forward traffic that has matched the rest of this rule to

If you want to use a different port on the Pi, just change the `--dport 5555` to whatever port you want to use; if you ever change the IP or port of your camera, change the `--to` part to match.

The above rule assumes you're using a TCP protocol (e.g. HTTP(S)) to connect to the camera, an assumption I came to because you used the word "browsing", which suggests a web browser. If you're using a UDP client instead (the specs mention it supports both TCP and UDP), change the `-p tcp` to `-p udp`. You could even do two versions of this rule, one for TCP and one for UDP, to support both!

Comment: @Fcm If this were a USB webcam, you'd be correct. Since this is an IP camera running across the network that the Pi's eth0 is connected to (or possibly directly connected to), then you have to NAT to the camera if you want it to be the "bridge" from the wlan network.

Comment: you are right, a bridge will do it.  My comment deleted.

Comment: Did what you said but I am facing another problem now.. When the Wlan0 network is connected then eth0 not working.. Any ideas?? Thanks..

Comment: @user28282 Make sure wlan0 and eth0 are both using different subnets; beyond that, there's too little to go on, but in any case it's really an entirely different question altogether.

Comment: Sorry about that, changed the subnets and now everything is working..

Comment: @user28282 Glad to hear that! You could also solve that issue with static routes, but again that's a topic for a separate question -- and besides, it's just easier to use different subnets.